# Is there a way to filter a dataframe based on a specific value but also keep all other values for the unique identifier using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

What I mean is that let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
UID  A  
1    Yes  
1    No  
2    No  
2    No  
3    Yes  
3    No  
4    Yes  
4    Yes
```

I want to produce a dataframe where any UID that has a yes is included, even the other instances of the UID is a "No".

```
UID  A  
1    Yes  
1    No  
3    Yes  
3    No  
4    Yes  
4    Yes
```

Is there a way to do this using Pandas or any other library in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `isin`

```
df = df.loc[df.UID.isin(df.loc[df.A=='Yes','UID'])]
df
Out[323]: 
   UID    A
0    1  Yes
1    1   No
4    3  Yes
5    3   No
6    4  Yes
7    4  Yes
```

Comment: Hey @BEN_YO, I just want to make sure I understand what you did there. You first got all the UID's that have A as 'Yes' and then you got all the rows that contain those UIDS.

Comment: @Harsha that is correct , by using this the running time should be better than any groupby method ~ :-)

Comment: Hi, this worked for me, but what if I had two things to filter on, like lets say A included Yes, No and Maybe as possible choices i wanted all UIDs that included Yes and Maybe?

Comment: @qshahryar `df.groupby('UID').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['Yes','Maybe']).isin(x['A']).all())
`

Comment: @BEN_YO, that works perfectly. Just one last question, is it possible to filter based on either Yes or Maybe, so any UID that has either Yes or Maybe would exist in the new data frame?

Comment: @qshahryar change to any  df.groupby('UID').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['Yes','Maybe']).isin(x['A']).any())

Answer (score 1):

I would use a groupby + filter operation:

```py
result = (
    df.groupby('UID')
      .filter(lambda g: g['A'].eq('Yes').any()
)
```

And that gives me:

```
   UID    A
0    1  Yes
1    1   No
4    3  Yes
5    3   No
6    4  Yes
7    4  Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
list = [x for x in df['UID'] if df['A'] == 'Yes']
dfnew = df.query('UID == list & A == ("Yes","No")')
```

Not elegant but worth a try